# Google android maps api v2 Show Marker Title Always

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a **google maps v2** in my android application and some markers on it. When user click one of these markers, a title popup comes. How can I show these titles always without user click?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just call `Marker.showInfoWindow();`.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#showInfoWindow()

Comment: Thank you it helpmed me a bit. But i want to show all titles at same time. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 50):

Something like that:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
    .title("Your position")).showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: its work completely when default info window is use but when i use Info window adapter for custom info window than how to info window default open??

Answer (score 15):

You can do this:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition).title("Your text"));
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Answer (score 10):

For displaying marker titles on the map around the markers, none of the solutions I found on internet worked for me so I rolled up my sleeves and made this library which solves this problem for me, hopefully it will help others too:

https://github.com/androidseb/android-google-maps-floating-marker-titles

Here is a preview of how it works:

[image: preview]

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. It's a very useful answer. Thanks for the gif also.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not so good in some implementation but here is my code:

```
public BitmapDescriptor getBitmapFromView(String title) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.marker_tooltip, null);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tooltips_title)).setText(title);

        //Get the dimensions of the view. In my case they are in a dimen file
        int width = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tooltips_width);
        int height = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tooltips_height);

        int measuredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        view.measure(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        view.draw(canvas);

        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }

...
marker.setIcon(getBitmapFromView(marker.getTitle()));
...
```

I implemented this in a fragment in a map app with some variations. For example, with a custom Info Window and some events on the map but its implementation was required to show all marker title at the same time. **Let me know if it was helpful for you too**

**the ACTIVITY of "activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.tooltips_width)" variable is a property in the fragment**

Comment: Thanks man! Also, to measure width of text, you can use 
textView.paint.measureText(title) to make bitmap width depend on content

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am a bit late in answering this one but the code below works for me:

//add this library

```
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

//then use the method below

```
public void makersMaker(GoogleMap googleMap){
    IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);                            
    Marker marker1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLng(-1.3177336,36.8251902));                  
    marker1.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon("Marker 1")));
    Marker marker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(-1.2857399,36.8214088)));                
    marker2.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon("Marker 2")));
}
```