# Android Google map api add title to my marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can I add a title to my marker in this case

```
      mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                                    .center(new LatLng(postionsList.get(i).getLatitude(), postionsList.get(i).getLongitude()))
                                    .radius(100)
                                    .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                                    .fillColor(Color.RED));

                            bitmapMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google android maps api v2 Show Marker Tittle Always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579426/google-android-maps-api-v2-show-marker-tittle-always)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like this

[image: circle marker google maps]

try

```
IconGenerator iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getActivity());
iconGenerator.setTextAppearance(myColor));
iconGenerator.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE);
Bitmap iconBitmap = iconGenerator.makeIcon(myText);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(myLatLng)
   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconBitmap)).anchor(0.5f, 0.6f));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MarkerOptions` method with this, There is a title sub method that will add title to your marker.

```
MarkerOptions marker = new markerOptions().position(<your LatLng>).title(<your title>)
mMap.addMarker(marker)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use code:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(postionsList.get(i).getLatitude(), postionsList.get(i).getLongitude()))
            .title("your_title_name")
            .draggable(true) //avoid if dont want drag-able marker
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(your_drawable_marker_image)));
```